# Excel VBA notify all read-only viewers of change

Tags: excel, vba

I was thinking it would be a nice convenience if, while a bunch of people are viewing the same workbook for read-only, they could be notified with a pop-up on their screen every time the workbook has been updated. That way they know right away what they are looking at may no longer be accurate. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a crafty little way of doing what you want. The idea is to get `FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName)`, the date the workbook file was last modified. You first get this date at the time of opening the workbook, store it in a cell in your workbook, and then check back periodically whether `FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName)` returns a date different from what was stored.

In this example I store the date in `Sheet1.Range("A1")`, but you could store it in a hidden sheet or wherever.

In your `ThisWorkbook` module, define the `Workbook_Open` event as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    userNotified = False

    'Store date last modified.
    dateLastModifiedWhenOpened = FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName)

    'How often will we check back?
    runTimeInterval = TimeValue("00:00:05")

    'Set timer for next check.
    Application.OnTime Now + runTimeInterval, _
        "CheckWhetherThisWorkbookFileModifiedSinceOpening"
End Sub
```

In a code module:

```
Public dateLastModifiedWhenOpened As Date
Public nextRunTime As Date
Public runTimeInterval As Date
Public userNotified As Boolean

Sub CheckWhetherThisWorkbookFileModifiedSinceOpening()

    If Not FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName) = dateLastModifiedWhenOpened Then
        MsgBox "This workbook file has been modified since you opened it." _
            & vbCrLf & "Modified at: " & FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
        userNotified = True
    Else
        'Set timer for next check.
        nextRunTime = Now + runTimeInterval
        Application.OnTime nextRunTime, _
            "CheckWhetherThisWorkbookFileModifiedSinceOpening"
    End If

End Sub
```

It may be a good idea to clean up upon closing the workbook. In your `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not userNotified Then
        'Cancel the next check.
        Application.OnTime nextRunTime, _
            "CheckWhetherThisWorkbookFileModifiedSinceOpening", , False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I decided not to do this, although I appreciate the help. I just found it too complicated. I decided I would just prevent users from making changes to a document if it has since been changed since it was opened, using a little trick (timestamping when the the workbook was opened, and checking that against the last time it was saved). That doesn't really answer my original question, but it does solve my problem. So I guess consider this thread closed.

Comment: +1 Honestly, the method suggested above is no way complicated and I cannot think of any other way more simpler than this.

Comment: OK, since this might be the answer someone else is looking for I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can share your workbook via the Review ribbon, Share Workbook.

In the advanced options you can set "Update changes" to as often as 5 minutes.  In your case you probably want "Just see other users' changes".

Comment: It is a long and complicated story, but I cannot use share workbook. In a nutshell it is because this board is essentially an electronic kanban, and 'Share Workbook' does not support merging changes to shapes.